# How to use the asp.net core newest integrationtest framework to test microserivces

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, microservices, identityserver4

I am now write the microservices applications:

One Asp.Net Core Web MVC as the client.

One Asp.Net Core Web MVC with the Identity server 4 as the authentication server.

One Asp.Net Core Web API as the web API Server.

And the flow is

1. MVC client send the request to authentication server getting the token
2. MVC use the token to request the web API to get the protected data.

above work is done.

Then I want use the Integration test framework to test the work flow.
So I start do it by using the customize WebApplicationFactory .
Detail about this framework here:
[Integration tests in ASP.NET Core: Customize WebApplicationFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-webapplicationfactory)

I can not interact 3 services together.

Sample code's zip file here ,you can direct open the .sln file using vs2017:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/files/2637031/IdSample.zip

So how to do Integration test with the microservices.

Comment: Having questions or answers dependent on an external link are considered low quality on this site, as if that link becomes stale, the question or answer becomes meaningless.  Please add a [mcve] to the question

Comment: Got it , I had edited it.